# AEM integration with Yahoo Tag manager

Tags: aem

I need to integrate AEM with yahoo tag manager but there is not much documentation available for that.Please help me with any links or steps if somebody has implemented it.

I am using AEM 6.0 with SP2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are to integrate the JS snippet generated for your project with AEM, you need to follow the steps for the Generic Analytics Implementation as specified in documentation at Adobe site  [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/administer/integration/external-providers.html)

Either you can create your own Cloud Service or use the existing one (`/etc/cloudservices/generic-tracker`), in that cloud service add the JS script generated. Setting up the CloudService with your content will include the js snippet on your pages.

Ignore that fact that it says "Generic Analytics", it can be reused for such script inclusions.
One such reference for google tag manager can be referenced [here](http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2014/01/integrating-adobe-experience-manager-aem-google-tag-manager.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct OOTB or cloud service to achieve this.
But, I can think of 3 ways to do so:-

**Option 1:**- Using "Generic Analytics Snippet" Cloud Service

a. Open the Tools console.

b. From the left pane expand Cloud Services Configurations.

c. Double-click on Generic Analytics Snippet to open the page:

d. Click on the + to add a new configuration using the dialog; at a minimum 
assign a name, for example google analytics:
[image]

e.Click Create, the snippet dialog will open immediately - paste the appropriate javascript snippet into the field:
[image]
f.Click OK to save.

**Reference Documentation Link:- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/integration/external-providers.html**

**Option 2:-** "Creating a Custom Cloud Service"

**Full process of doing it can be found here :- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/extending/cloud-service-configurations/creating-a-custom-cloud-service.html**

**Option 3:-** "Directly Adding JavaScript to Page's Code"

Thanks and Regards

Kautuk Sahni

([Adobe AEM Forum](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.html))